# Is there a way to fail one step in Allure Reports and continue the same test case execution using Jasmine Protractor framework?

Tags: node.js, selenium, jasmine, protractor, allure

I understand that this is not advisable but I have to test a big scenario and need to continue testing even if one/multiple steps fail.

I want to be able to report that accurately using Allure reports. The framework is built on Protractor 5, Jasmine 2 and JavaScript ES2016.

```
function addStep(name, status) {
 allure.createStep(name, () => {
     testutils.logger().debug('${ name }');
     browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) => {
        allure.createAttachment(name, () =>
            Buffer.from(png, 'base64'), 'image/png')();
    });
})();
```

}

Basically, how do I add the status value to the allure step, and then continue on to next steps?

Answer (score 1):

`expect(false).toBe(true)` will fail the test case, but will continue the execution

Obviously that has to be conditional. For example you want to fail it if element is not present,

`expect(await elem.isPresent()).toBe(true)`

that will fail the test case but will execute everything after that

Comment: Thanks. Adding this fails the overall test case but each step has the status as passed. Is there a way to fail the steps too?

Comment: that's different. look up `failFast` plugin @Naveen